# Select COUNT identical values without GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I want to make an SQL statement where I fetch all the data from the table, but I want to include a new column that counts the identical values in a column.
In this case in each row I want to see a column that counts the identical `vin` numbers.
I tried

```
SELECT 
   *, 
   COUNT( DISTINCT vin) AS identical 
FROM table
```

but it gives me an error:
`In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'table'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`.

Currently I'm not able to modify the database, and I'm also not 100% sure that changing sql_mode would do the thing.

```
+----+-----+---------+---------+---------+
| id | vin | status1 | status2 | status3 |
+----+-----+---------+---------+---------+
|  1 | 111 |       1 |       0 |       1 |
|  2 | 222 |       1 |       1 |       0 |
|  3 | 333 |       0 |       1 |       0 |
|  4 | 333 |       0 |       1 |       1 |
|  5 | 333 |       0 |       0 |       1 |
|  6 | 222 |       1 |       1 |       0 |
+----+-----+---------+---------+---------+
```

I want to see something like this:

```
+----+-----+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
| id | vin | status1 | status2 | status3 | identical |
+----+-----+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
|  1 | 111 |       1 |       0 |       1 |         1 |
|  2 | 222 |       1 |       1 |       0 |         2 |
|  3 | 333 |       0 |       1 |       0 |         3 |
|  4 | 333 |       0 |       1 |       1 |         3 |
|  5 | 333 |       0 |       0 |       1 |         3 |
|  6 | 222 |       1 |       1 |       0 |         2 |
+----+-----+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: *"I'm also not 100% sure that changing sql_mode would do the thing."* if you disable the sql_mode only_full_group_by you are playing russian roulette with your resultset as you don't know for sure the data is valid or not meaning related to the group

Comment: No, there is only 3 rows where the `vin` is `333`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MySQL 8+ we can use `COUNT` as an analytic function here:

```
SELECT
    id,
    vin,
    status1,
    status2,
    status3,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY vin) identical
FROM yourTable;
```

In earlier versions of MySQL, we can try joining to a subquery which finds the `vin` counts:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.vin,
    t1.status1,
    t1.status2,
    t1.status3,
    t2.cnt AS identical
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT vin, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY vin
) t2
    ON t1.vin = t2.vin;
```

Comment: I couldn't try the version 8+ method, but the second one works as I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
select t.vin, t.status1 t.status2, t.status3, sq.identical from table t
left join (SELECT vin, 
   COUNT( *) AS identical 
FROM table
group by vin) as sq on sq.vin=t.vin
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). Additionally, any time you find yourself with enumerated columns (above, say, 2), alarm bells should start ringing.

Comment: Well, for a simplified table where the problem is not in the columns itself or the table structure, I thought that satatus1, 2, 3 would do the thing for the representation.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this as

```
SELECT `d`.*,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `data` WHERE `vin`=`d`.`vin`) AS `identical`
FROM `data` as `d` ;
```

Comment: why the `CASE WHEN ... END` as sanity check? It shouldn't really matter if it's there or not..

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks for pointing that out, i have updated it,